# Recovering free disk space to expand Ubuntu partition

Tags: disk-utility, partition, unix

I have a dual boot MacBook with Retina Display running macOS and Ubuntu,  and I need to give more space to the Ubuntu OS.

I've already reduced the macOS partition but I don't know how to *expose* the free space to be used by Linux.

I've followed the suggestions from [klanomath](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath) on [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154964/resizing-or-expanding-a-corestorage-volume/176557#176557) and [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153523/resizing-dual-boot-partitions-in-yosemite/153748#153748) to extract the useful information but without results.

From the command line I got:

```
gpt -r -vv show /dev/disk0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=500277790720; sectorsize=512; blocks=977105060
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 977105059
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  781905376      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  782315016    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  783584552        728         
  783585280  175779840      4  GPT part - 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
  959365120   17739776      5  GPT part - 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
  977104896        131         
  977105027         32         Sec GPT table
  977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

And:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            400.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:           Linux Filesystem                         90.0 GB    disk0s4
   5:                 Linux Swap                         9.1 GB     disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +300.0 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 FAD2BA28-C2C9-4620-B468-313C951FEBD6
                                 Unencrypted
```

Finally:

```
diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 91564EA0-5F5F-4793-9A94-6696D18A5F13
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         400335552512 B (400.3 GB)
    Free Space:   99983228928 B (100.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume E6DE2625-E3CA-425C-8682-549068D4F452
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     400335552512 B (400.3 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 2618AE6A-3248-4FCC-90DF-71691BF72365
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume FAD2BA28-C2C9-4620-B468-313C951FEBD6
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          299999997952 B (300.0 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFSX
```

I've tried with no results:

```
sudo diskutil cs resizeDisk E6DE2625-E3CA-425C-8682-549068D4F452 300g
Started CoreStorage operation
Error: -69722: You can't perform this resize unless it has a booter (target partition is probably too small)
```

Besides 300 GB is the size of the logical partition.

From my understanding I need to:

1. Shrink the Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD from 400 GB to 300 GB (Logical Volume)
2. Make the free 100 GB available to Linux (if there's something to do).
3. Extend Linux partition to use the new 100 GB.

Can anyone help me how to process to give to Linux the unused disk space, please?

Comment: You just resized the Logical Volume but not the Logical Volume Group. You should have executed following command: `diskutil cs resizeStack FAD2BA28-C2C9-4620-B468-313C951FEBD6 300g`! This command may still work though. If it doesn't work, resize the Logical Volume to 400g again and repeat the resizeStack command.

Comment: I followed your tips, but unfortunately doesn't work.

I expanded the volume to 400g again, but trying to shrink down again yields the same error:

1. diskutil cs resizeVolume FAD2BA28-C2C9-4620-B468-313C951FEBD6 0 (expand to 400gb)

2. diskutil cs resizeStack FAD2BA28-C2C9-4620-B468-313C951FEBD6 300g
The Core Storage Logical Volume UUID is FAD2BA28-C2C9-4620-B468-313C951FEBD6
Started CoreStorage operation
Checking prerequisites for resizing Logical-Physical volume stack
Error: -69722: You can't perform this resize unless it has a booter (target partition is probably too small)

Comment: An additional source of error may be the MBR (instead of a pMBR)!

Comment: Thanks for your help.Finally I've gave up and reinstall both mac and ubuntu having in mind to give enough space for each one.